# What does external javascript can access on website. Asking for security reasons

Tags: javascript, security

What data can external javascript fetch from a website, if it placed in website's `<head>` tag? For example cookies, local storage? How can it harm a website's security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much everything.

The origin of a script is determined by the page its `<script>` element appears on. The external script can access the same things as a script you wrote yourself (including using Ajax to make HTTP requests to the same origin).

> How can it harm a website's security?

You've given them *all* the keys and turned off the alarms.

Comment: Just *some* examples of what could be done by a malicious script: 1. You can capture all user input and send it to the attacker. A keylogger that only works for the page. 2. You can redirect the user to another page that *looks like* the page they were on but it's actually controlled by the attacker. This can even be hidden to only happen when the tab is not in focus, so the user doesn't notice it reloads. 3. You can get all cookies, local storage, and session storage data for the site. Hope there wasn't any sensitive information there. 4. You can use the browser to perform a a DDoS attack.